# identifying new GPOs pushed down from Active Directory

Tags: internet-explorer, group-policy

How do you identify the *recent* and Group Policy Objects that have been pushed down to a client machine?

I am trying to identify if any new IE settings were pushed down recently.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pushing RSoP to a file then compare? Something like GPRESULT -h GPEDIT.html